# 1920 rowhouse project - rewiring

Tags: electrical

Finishing rewiring the upstairs and was told that the bathroom had to be on its own 20a circuit. No problem did my run but uhoh it's a little short well by a couple feet. Ugh that 12 gauge wire was a pain to snake through all joists holes that once hade porcelain tubes. So I thought ok I can pop a utility outlet and pigtail from there but nope! That gfci outlet must be dedicated circuit and can only have loads 10A or less on that circuit . Am I sol? Could I forego the pigtail at the hallway and make it the first in the circuit series and be in code?

Comment: Pigtail is usually a few inches, not feet. Can you put in a box where the run ends and then a simple wirenutted extension for the remaining few feet? With a blank cover on the box?

Comment: Thanks bib. That could be a solution I wasn't going to have pigtails a few feet long.  I was think to do almost the same thing you suggested but with a receptacle. A blank would be so pretty and someone later maybe tempted to add a receptacle there.  Maybe I need to suck it up and do the run again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a junction box in a location the wiring *can* reach.  Make a splice inside the junction box to get to where you need to go.  Splices are no big deal if done right - really.

This location must be accessible without dismantling any part of the house.  So it can't be behind trim or drywall.  But putting it inside a closet with floating shelves is fine.   If all the person has to do is empty out a closet and lift out a shelf.

The junction box will have a blank cover, unless it's in the bathroom.

Or, if it really makes you bat crazy to have a blank cover, then fine.  Use a deep box at least 20 cubic inches.  Make the bathroom splice and push it into the back of the box.  Then bring over another circuit and attach a receptacle to that circuit. That's allowed as long as the box has enough cubic inches to handle all the wires.  Don't mix the neutrals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  One more question - so the bathroom/circuit can only have GFCI outlets which are only in the bathroom? Seems like a waste of a run if it is only connected to one receptacle.  It sounds like I can add the bathroom lighting since i am pretty sure it will never reach 10a.  Also the circuit cannot leave the bathroom correct?

Comment: That receptacle circuit can either a) serve receptacles only, in any number of bathrooms.  b) serve any loads in only one bathroom.  I dislike b) because a hair dryer+curler trip plunges you into darkness, leaving you tangled in cords and red hot tools.  http://ecmweb.com/qampa/code-qa-120  (when reading this note that an "outlet" is a hardwired connection too, e.g. lights fan heater).

Comment: On the back of the blank junction box cover, write "GFCI circuit to bathroom" in perm. marker.  Be nice to the next guy.

Comment: Or for that matter you could even put a deadface GFCI there and have that be the bathroom GFCI.  If it's sanely findable.  I was going to suggest that, but couldn't find an opening.  Thanks.